# how to remove outliers from binary thinned image

Tags: matlab, binary, thin, morphological-analysis

I am working on fingerprint thinning,but there are some small lines or outliers in image which are to be removed..Image1 is the binary image and Image2 is the thinned version of Image1.how can I remove the outliers..thanks in advance.[image: binary image] [image: thinned image]